# SQlite AUTOINCREMENT with Statement Binding

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, data-binding

Created a table

> "CREATE TABLE student ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name
>   TEXT, course TEXT)"

Now when trying to insert a row like

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO student" +" VALUES (?,?)";
SQLiteStatement statement = myWriteableDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
statement.clearBindings();
statement.bindString(2, "Some Name");
statement.bindString(3, "Some Course");
statement.execute();
```

this throws an exception saying

```
table student has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied: , while compiling: INSERT INTO student VALUES (?,?);
```

Why is this exception even though I have made **id** column as AUTOINCREMENT.

Comment: [If **no column-list** is specified then the number of values inserted into each row must be the **same as the number of columns** in the table. In this case the result of evaluating the left-most expression from each term of the VALUES list is inserted into the left-most column of each new row, and so forth for each subsequent expression. If a **column-list** is specified, then the number of values in each term of the VALUE list must match the number of specified columns.](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PRIMARY KEY` autogeneration only kicks in if a `NULL` is inserted into the column.

Either specify the columns you want to insert to:

```
INSERT INTO student(name,course) VALUES ...
```

so that the `id` column gets a `NULL` default value, or explicitly insert a NULL value, for example

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(NULL,?,?)
```

Also check your bind indices. They are not correct - it's the index of the `?` in the query string, not the index of the column in the table.

Answer (score 1):

First you have an error in yours `bindString` calls, you only have 2 `?` signs in your query, the first make reference to the name column and the second `?` make reference to the course column.

If you want use the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('name', 'course')
```

you need change your code to (see the query):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO student" +" VALUES (NULL, ?,?)";
SQLiteStatement statement = myWriteableDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
statement.clearBindings();
statement.bindString(1, "Some Name");
statement.bindString(2, "Some Course");
statement.execute();
```

Or you can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO student (name, course) VALUES ('first', 'second')
```

In this case you can use this code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO student (name, course)" +" VALUES (?,?)";
SQLiteStatement statement = myWriteableDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
statement.clearBindings();
statement.bindString(1, "Some Name");
statement.bindString(2, "Some Course");
statement.execute();
```